# Casting timestamp to integer issues

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with pgsql query that is throwing an "ERROR:  integer out of range".

What I am trying to accomplish is to check if date contained valid_to field (of 'timestamp without timezone' type) is exactly an (N * interval) apart from current date. In example of failing query I am using "7776000" as interval (90 days) and "1399327200" as current date in unix time.

What works:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (CAST((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM et.valid_to) - 1399327200 ) as integer) % 7776000) as modulo
FROM example_table et 
WHERE et.valid_to IS NOT NULL
```

What does not:

```
WITH table_refined as (
    SELECT 
        *,
        (CAST((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM et.valid_to) - 1399327200 ) as integer) % 7776000) as modulo
    FROM example_table et 
    WHERE et.valid_to IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT * from table_refined WHERE modulo=0
```

Nor this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        (CAST((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM et.valid_to) - 1399327200 ) as integer) % 7776000) as modulo
    FROM example_table et
    WHERE et.valid_to IS NOT NULL 
)
AS table_temp 
WHERE table_temp.modulo = 0
```

As I am first substracting current date from timestamp, then value that is castet to integer shouldn't be out of integer bounds. There are some NULLs of course, but as first query passes OK, it's rather not the problem.

Comment: Can be greatly simplified with `extract(epoch from age(et.valid_to))` . It'd be really helpful if you'd provide a dummy table with a sample value for `et.valid_to` that triggers the error you see - right now you're showing the SQL but not the input to the SQL that results in the error. Also, PostgreSQL version? Finally, please use the `{}` button to indent your SQL; it's much more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the cause of this error by creating dummy table with some extreme records. The version was 9.0, and I'll surely use `{}` in future.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the reason - among the records there were one with 'valid_to' field with '2050-01-01' date, and that one surely caused all this fuss. Therefore, I added

```
AND valid_to < '2100-01-01'
```

to my query what made it finally work. Although unix time is to reach integer limit in 2038, it looks like postgresql casting make it working up to the unsigned integer max value, so limiting records to year 2100 works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the error cause but you can avoid all that by using intervals

```
select *,
    valid_to,
    valid_to - currrent_date - 90 * interval '1 day'
from et
where
    valid_to is not null
    and
    valid_to - currrent_date = 90 * interval '1 day'
```

Comment: Of course I know about intervals, but I need something different - to check if also multiplied intervals matches the valid_to date.